# PythonSDK from Conceptive Engineering

Tags: python, linux

Does anybody have experience installing PythonSDK (2.7.2) from Conceptive Engineering using their linux package?

Windows version had an installer and went great. Would like to now use on linux box also.

The linux version ships as an archive. It does not seem to be organized like a typical python installation site. No docs/readme/executables in the top level (so seemingly no installer scripts).

Their tech support is kinda slow and docs are slim. Was hoping someone had personal experience.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need an SDK?

Comment: Its not an 'SDK' per-se, that is just the name of the pre-packaged/compiled python distribution. I think they refer to it as 'SDK' because of the packages/binaries that are included, it ships as something like a Python-QT4 rapid development suite.